# How to install Tor with Meek support

Tags: tor

Is there any easy way to install and run tor with meek support on Ubuntu ?
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek

Beside it is possible to download the bundle archive I'm interested in a native way:
 - installing Tor is enough or I need any extra software to enable meek ?
 - how to configure `torrc` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment the meek packages are landing in debian so we can expect them to arrive in ubuntu too.

**UPDATE**
Previous info are not working fine anymore, it looks there is now a repository for debian unstable ... so I changed my previous answer with this one:

**1 Add Repository**

[Repository](https://people.debian.org/~infinity0/apt/) (info on the repository page).

**2. Install `meek-client` package**

```
sudo apt-get install meek-client
```

**3. Update your tor configuration**

Now edit you tor configuration file `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/tor/torrc
```

Add the meek plugin to it

```
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec  /usr/bin/meek-client
```

And some meek bridges:

```
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:3 url=https://az668014.vo.msecnd.net/ front=ajax.aspnetcdn.com
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:2 url=https://d2zfqthxsdq309.cloudfront.net/ front=a0.awsstatic.com
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you also need to edit the Ubuntu AppArmor definition - otherwise you will get 'permission denied' errors. In the file `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor`, add the line `/usr/bin/meek-client ix,` at the end. Then restart AppArmor, or the whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can clone **meek git repository** and then install it with **Golang** and then start Tor with defined torrc file:

```
git clone https://git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git
cd meek/meek-client
export GOPATH=~/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
go get -insecure
go build
tor -f torrc
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install the browser bundle with meek installed here : https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek
Just follow the steps :)

Comment: It's considered bad practice to have a link-only answer here. Please provide a brief set of steps needed to solve the problem, and provide the link as a reference (or for further reading).

Comment: sorry but I cannot consider a valid answer: 1.the link you shared is the same I have added in the question, 2. I have specifically wrote that I don't want to use the bundle ...